# Separate loggers defined and configured for different modules and getting message multiple times

Tags: python, logging

I have two classes both of which have their own loggers (defined and configured). The only thing common in all the loggers is that they are logging into the same file. All the loggers are defined and configured in the **init** method of the classes. Here is something similar to what I am doing

```
class One:

def __init__(self):
    pass

def set_params(self):
    log_file_name  = r"C:\Users\Sample\SamplePath\SampleLogs.log"
    log_format = "%(name)s :  %(levelname)s :  %(asctime)s : [%(filename)s] : [%(funcName)s] : %(message)s"
    three = Three(log_file_name, log_format)
    self.param = [log_file_name, log_format, three]

def get_param(self):
    return self.param
```

This is the parent class which sets up the log_file, log_format.

Then there is a **class Three** which is being instantiated in **class One**

```
class Three:
def __init__(self, log_file_name, log_format):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    self.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

def sample_method(self):
    self.logger.info("Sample Method called")
```

The object of **class Three** is being used in **class Two** (which again has its own logger)

```
class Two:
def __init__(self, log_file_name, log_format, class_three_object):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    self.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    class_three_object.sampleMethod()
```

Finally the main method that is used for calling is

```
def main():
first = One()
params = first.get_param()
second = Two(params[0], params[1], params[2])
```

All the three classes are in different modules. I understand that Python logs multiple times when we attach handler to a logger and its ancestors. But if each class has its own logger, should it happen?
I thought it may be possible if instantiate **class Three** twice. Therefore I instantiated it once and passed it as an object to **class Two** but turns out that was a blunt guess on my part. 
Can someone please help me with this?
Thank You

EDIT 1: all the classes are in three different files. The main() function that is present is called in the file containing second class when **name** == "**main**"

Comment: without knowing your file structure it's hard to answer. if you put all your classes in the same file, all of them will have the same logger since you use `__name__` which doesn't reference to a class name, only to module.

Comment: @m1keil all the classes are in different files. I will add that in the edit. Thank you.